# Pydantic data conversion and PyCharm's PyTypeChecker

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy, pydantic

According to the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#data-conversion), "*pydantic may cast input data to force it to conform to model field types [...] This is a deliberate decision of pydantic, and in general it's the most useful approach.*"

The following code works as expected:

```
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel
>>> class Foo(BaseModel):
...     bar: int

>>> foo = Foo(bar="3")     # Passing a string
```

And mypy doesn't complain, but PyCharm's PyTypeChecker does:

```
Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead
```

Is there any way I can keep using automatic data conversion and avoid the inspection error (other than disabling the inspection)?

Using Python 3.8.10, Pydantic 1.8.2, Mypy 0.910, PyCharm <s>2021.2.2</s> 2021.2.3

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pydantic` [Pycharm plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12861-pydantic). Its step-by-step setup can be found on [official page](https://koxudaxi.github.io/pydantic-pycharm-plugin/type-checker-for-pydantic/).

As a solution you can specify the types you use as *parsable* (or *acceptable*) and disable warning about them in configuration file. This disabling will only work for the types that you specified. For example, so:

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.pydantic-pycharm-plugin.parsable-types]
# int field accepts to parse str
"int" = ["str"]

[tool.pydantic-pycharm-plugin]
# You can set higlith level (default is "warning")
# You can select it from "warning",  "weak_warning", "disable"
parsable-type-highlight = "disable"
acceptable-type-highlight = "disable"
```

By the way, this plugin is mentioned on official pydantic [page](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/pycharm_plugin/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just found I was happily using the Pydantic plugin (v. 0.3.8). I probably installed it some months ago.
However, the instructions insist on disabling the builtin type checker. But when I go to Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections, and filter with "type checker", only the the Pydantic type checker appears. There's no built-in checker I can disable.
Anyway, I tried activating the Pydantic type checker and creating the toml file, and the behavior is the same as before.